# Access to a class property in a callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom-events

I started recently to learn patterns in JavaScript and trying to understand how it is working by simulating "classes". So most probably this error is coming because of a bad understanding of how it is executed.

I have the following general class:

```
var Collection = (function(){
    function Collection(){
       this.collection = {};
    }

    var p = Collection.prototype;
    p.callback = function(data){collection = data;}
    
    return Collection;
})();
```

API is a singleton class. `Get_Data` method will execute some Ajax call but so far it is just an object. The singleton class is as follow:

```
var WebService = (function(){
    var instance;
    var init = function(){
        return {
             get_data: function(callback){
                  // Dump data without accessing the Server
                  callback({'id':1234, 'data':"hello world"})
             }
        }
    }
    
    return {
        get_instance: function(){
            if(!instance)
                instance = init();

            return instance;
        }
    }
})();
```

At some point I create a `Collection` class and get some data from some source (it will be from a web service but so far I'm just using an object).

```
var collection_objects = new Collection();
var api = WebService.get_instance();
api.get_data(collection_objects.callback);
```

I'm using a callback method (name callback for simplicity) in the collection data that should update the model data. My issue is that in the callback I'm not accessing to the collection property. I'm actually creating a new object called collection. At some point, I think that I should use `this`, but since I will use an Ajax call, I will have to save `this` in another variable commonly known as `self`. That's the theory I have read so far, but where do I have to use the `self`? Is that the approach?

Comment: Add the "var self = this;" somewhere class level. then use "self.collection" inside your callback function.

Comment: @MarvinSmit What do you mean with a class level? Because I tried adding it in the constructor, but then the object has two properties: collection and "self"("self" will contain another collection and "self", etc.). It is creating recursive object that contains another one, and another, etc... Is that right?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At some point, I think that I should use "this", but since I will use
>   an Ajax call, I will have to save "this" in another vble commonly
>   known as "self"

That's a trick to overcome `this` problem in javascript. In my opinion, that's not so good as the function ***is tightly coupled*** to a variable outside the current context.

A better solution is to use [.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to bind the context to be your collection_objects. Like this:

```
api.get_data(collection_objects.callback.bind(collection_objects));
```

And use `this` in your callback, in this case, `this` is the collection_objects instead of the global window object

```
p.callback = function(data){ this.collection = data;}
```

In general, a method should not be concerned about how it's called. It's very unintuitive and bad if `this` inside Collection's prototype method does not refer to a Collection instance. Therefore, we should call the function in the context of a Collection instance. To avoid forgetting to use `.bind`, we could try another solution with `call` or `apply`:

```
get_data: function(context,callback){
    // Dump data without accessing the Server
    callback.call(context,{'id':1234, 'data':"hello world"});
}
```

And use it like this:

```
api.get_data(collection_objects,collection_objects.callback);
```

Internally, `.bind` uses something like `call` or `apply` to achieve the goal.

```
Function.prototype.bind = function(){
   var fn=this,args=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),object=args.shift();
   return function(){
      return fn.apply(object,
        args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
      };
};
```

This code is extracted from the book: [Secret of the javascript ninja](http://books.google.com.vn/books/about/Secrets_of_the_JavaScript_Ninja.html?id=ab8CPgAACAAJ&redir_esc=y). This code could be used as a polyfill in case the browser does not support `.bind` method natively.

Comment: Do I have to apply that .bind whenever I'm using that function? Isn't it like prone to errors if you forget to use the .bind method?